# INLINE Pragma in combination with type classes

Tags: haskell, ghc

Given the following code (copied from the attoparsec library) what does the inline pragma do? I suppose it makes sense for only `fmapR` to be inlined, but not the other `fmap`s which are defined in other Functor instances.

```
instance Functor (IResult t) where
    fmap = fmapR
    {-# INLINE fmap #-}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inline pragma will copy the contents of the function (in this case `fmapR`) to the location where it is called, if the compiler can prove that the functor being used is `IResult`.

The function cannot be inlined in the following case, because the definition of `fmap` is not known:

```
f :: Functor f => f Int -> f Float
f = fmap fromIntegral
```

Here, however, it is known, because a certain functor is being used, and the function can be inlined:

```
f :: IResult Int -> IResult Float
f = fmap fromIntegral
-- rewritten to: f = fmapR fromIntegral; might be further inlined
```

Comment: Ah, so fmap is "rewritten" as fmapR, but fmapR might not be inlined, if I understand that correctly?